# How to use dependencies in an async method (not awaited method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a class with an scoped `_repository` and one async method `MethodAsync(....)` I call the method without await (fire and forget). I want to use the injected dependency after the await (in the catch), but the request is over at that time, and I got an error saying: Cannot access a disposed object.

I think getting that error is the expected behavior, but **How can I use injected dependencies in this way?** I could inject the ServiceProvider and ask for dependencies, but injecting the ServiceProvider is a bad practice. **How can I solve this without injecting the ServiceProvider?**

I call the method like this:

```
example.MethodAsync(....);//without await
```

This is the class

```
public class Example
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;

    public Example(Repository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task MethodAsync(....)
    {
        try
        {
            await DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _repository.Example.Remove(....);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What object is the error thrown in that is disposed?

Comment: You can resolve it by `await`ing your call. Your service is scoped, if you fire-forget the call, your DI will dispose it because the request is considered done.

Comment: I think in your (try) statement you use (using) statement so dispose object automate please show your repository class

Comment: @Jawad The error is on _repository object. The full error is: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'DbContext'.

Comment: @JohanP you're rigth, but, I want to NOT await.

Comment: @AkbarAsghari Im not using the 'using block'. The error is cause the request is over and the _repository is injected as scoped. My Repository class is a DbContext, but it could be any dependency

Comment: Probably you should inject the factory that will create the repository. Accordingly, the Dispose should be inside catch.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Interesting, inject a Factory for the Repository. Thanks

Comment: please use Interface for inject I don't see any interface for your repository

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164677/264697

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26698472/264697

Answer (score 1):

You are able to both execute it in a fire and forget manner while using the full DI capabilities by using a **job scheduler**.

By doing so, you are furthermore able to keep track of the state of the executed job. Furthermore configuring retry-on-failure would be feasible.

I am using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for this job:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Example>(service => service.MethodAsync());
```

Comment: I didn't know the library, it looks good. I'll take a look, although I'm trying to use a native way.

Comment: @satellitesatellite Imho "using the native way" would mean to create some kind of a job scheduler yourself.

Comment: I mean to no use an external library. Hangfire looks great, but I resolved it by injecting a Factory. This way I'm not using an external lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by adding a factory and creating a new scope manually like this:

```
// usage:
_ = exampleFactory.MethodAsync();  // discard operator, not awaited, fire-and-forget

public class Startup
{
    public async void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ExampleFactory>();  // this is important for dependencies not to be disposed of
        services.AddScoped<Example>();
        services.AddScoped<Repository>();
    }
}
public class ExampleFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    // make sure not to inject any scoped dependencies via constructor, it will throw
    public ExampleFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task MethodAsync()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var example = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Example>();
        return await example.MethodAsync();
    }
}
public class Example  // this class is unchanged
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;

    public Example(Repository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task MethodAsync(....)
    {
        try
        {
            await DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _repository.Example.Remove(....);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can create long-running fire-and-forget API endpoints.